# Method to add AWS EC2 t2 CPU balance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is there an ability to get CPU credits for t2 instances on AWS EC2? For example usually my server is not consuming the credits and I've accumulated many of them, but something happened and server was consuming too much CPU, wasted all the allocations. After that the server performs very badly under any load. Is there an option to buy/get credits in specific situation or I just have to stop instance, change it's type to similar non-burstable instance and wait while the performance stabilizes?

Comment: If you stop then start the instance, from memory you'll get a non-zero starting balance. Restart is different. The T2 unlimited below is a better option.

Comment: Yeah, way better, didn't know about unlimited. Surely will try it, better loose some money then stop the service for clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon just announced T2 Unlimited. By checking a box you enable sustained high CPU performance.

[T2 Unlimited](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-unlimited.html)

How much does this cost. Nothing until you use it. Then it is a flat additional price of $0.05 per vCPU hour.

> **T2 Unlimited Concepts**
>
> T2 Unlimited is a configuration option for T2 instances that can be
>   set at launch, or enabled at any time for a running or stopped T2
>   instance.
>
> T2 Unlimited instances can burst above the baseline for as long as
>   required. This enables you to enjoy the low T2 instance hourly price
>   for a wide variety of general-purpose applications, and ensures that
>   your instances are never held to the baseline performance. ​The basic
>   T2 hourly instance price automatically covers all CPU usage spikes if
>   the average CPU utilization of a T2 Unlimited instance over a rolling
>   24-hour period is at or below the baseline. For a vast majority of
>   general-purpose workloads, T2 Unlimited instances provide ample
>   performance without any additional charges. If the average CPU
>   utilization exceeds the baseline over a 24-hour period, there is a
>   flat additional rate of $0.05 per vCPU-hour.